# How do I display a link inline with a header?

Tags: html, css

All I want to do is put a header that has the page title and has a link to sign in that's inline with the title. This seems very simple but nothing I do is working. Here is what my code looks like:

HTML

```
<h1>Title</h1><a href="sign-in" class="signIn">Sign in</a>
```

CSS

```
.signIn {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}
```

The `float: right` works but it isn't inline with the title like I want it to be. Thanks.

Comment: I have also tried 'vertical-align: middle;' which also doesn't work

Comment: You would need to make the `h1` `display: inline` as well, it's `block` by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `h1` with the `a` in the markup

```
<a href="sign-in" class="signIn">Sign in</a><h1>Title</h1>
```

when leaving CSS as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Just place the `a` with the `.sign-in` class before the `h1`, as for tags with `float:right;` or `classes` with `float:right;` declarations should be declared first.

Here is the **[WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/YvBVv/)**

**The HTML Change**

```
<a href="sign-in" class="signIn">Sign in</a><h1>Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

tr y giving `float:left;` to `h1` tag

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

```
 h1{display: inline;}
    .signIn {
      display: block;
      float: right;
    }
```